# Django - How to populate manytomany field in forms by previously selected options by users

Tags: python, django, forms, orm

How can I populate manytomany form field with previous user selected subs.

In this code forms render choices with empty checkboxes.
I want checkboxes to show which subscriptions user subscribed to.

### models.py

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    SUBSCRIPTION_TYPES = (
        ('SUB1', _('sub 1')),
        ('SUB2', _('sub 2')),
    )

    subscription_type = models.CharField(choices=SUBSCRIPTION_TYPES, max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

class UserSubscription(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subscriptions = models.ManyToManyField(Subscription, related_name='subscriptions',
                                           related_query_name='subscriptions')
```

### forms.py

```
class SubscriptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserSubscription
        fields = ('subscriptions',)
        widgets = {
            'subscriptions': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        }
```

### views.py

```
class SubscriptionFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'profile/subscription.html'
    form_class = SubscriptionForm
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please do *not* create a `UserSubscription`, now you defined *two* junction tables. This will result in duplicate data, and will make queries less efficient, and more error-prone logic.

What you need is a `ManyToManyField` from the `Subscription` to the `User`, so:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    # …
    subscribers = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='subscriptions'
    )
```

Then we can define a form to select the `Subscription`s:

```
from django import forms

class SubscribingForm(forms.Form):
    subscriptions = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Subscription.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    )
```

Then in the view we can handle the form and subscribe the logged in user to all the subscriptions that have been selected:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.shortcuts import redirect

class SubscriptionFormView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'profile/subscription.html'
    form_class = SubscribingForm
    
    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super().get_initial()
        initial['subscriptions'] = self.request.user.subscriptions.all()
        return initial
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        subs = form.cleaned_data['subscriptions']
        self.request.user.subscriptions.add(*subs)
        return redirect('name-of-some-view')
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a class-based view to authenticated users with the
> [**`LoginRequiredMixin`** mixin [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin).

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was great but it didn't solve my problem. I want the check boxes to show as selected when a user is already subscribed to something.

Comment: @Allehparast: you can override `get_initial` to select the ones that people are already subscribed to, see edit.